# different elements with equal power in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$a$ and $b$ are distinct elements of group $G$ with identity $e$.

$a^m = b^m (m \in \mathbb{N})$

What can be said about $a$ and $b$ ?

If $G$ is Abelian, is it true that $ a^m = b^m  \Rightarrow a^m = b^m = e$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For instance in $\mathbb{Q}^*$, $2^4 = (-2)^4 = 16$.  Or in $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$, $3^2=4^2 = 2.$

Comment: Neither of those are groups under multiplication.

Comment: OK, I'll fix it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take matrices, i.e., let $G$ be the group $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Then
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr \frac{1}{2} & 1\end{pmatrix},\quad 
B=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \cr -\frac{1}{2} & -1\end{pmatrix},  
$$
both satisfy
$$
A^2=B^2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
For an abelian matrix group, take the invertible diagonal matrices in $G$, and
$A=diag(1,i)$ and $B=diag(1,-i)$. Then $A^2=B^2=diag(1,-1)\neq e=diag(1,1)$.